# PDFBOX2.0: java heap stack error

Tags: java, pdfbox

I've done test in windows server 2000 with JDK 1.6

As a result of test, The most of PDF files are correctly converted. But some files are not converted and return error message(Java heap space error).

So, i have also done test in Windows 10 with JDK 1.7.
In that case, They are completely converted.

I want to know why the situation is happened.

Below this text, I post my test environment.

Testing Environment.

1. PDFBox Version : 2.0.0
2. OS : Windows server 2000
3. RAM : 4GB
4. JDK : 1.6
5. Eclipse version : Indogo
6. Eclipse Stack size : -Xms1024m, -Xmx1024m
7. Error Message :

   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
   at java.awt.image.DataBufferByte.(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.createDataBuffer(Unknown Source)
   at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.(Unknown Source)
   at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.createCompatibleWritableRaster(Unknown Source)
   at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.createCompatibleWritableRaster(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.DCTFilter.fromBGRtoRGB(DCTFilter.java:245)
   at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.DCTFilter.decode(DCTFilter.java:170)
   at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSInputStream.create(COSInputStream.java:69)
   at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.createInputStream(COSStream.java:163)
   at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream.createInputStream(PDStream.java:234)
   at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject.(PDImageXObject.java:147)
   at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.PDXObject.createXObject(PDXObject.java:69)
   at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getXObject(PDResources.java:385)
   at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.graphics.DrawObject.process(DrawObject.java:53)
   at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:814)
   at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:471)
   at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:445)
   at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:149)
   at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:187)
   at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderPage(PDFRenderer.java:208)
   at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:139)
   at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(PDFRenderer.java:80)
   at imageconvertor.image.pdfToImage2.pdfToImage(pdfToImage2.java:49)
   at imageconvertor.image.App.main(App.java:15)

Comment: You mention the *Eclipse Stack size* but what is the stack size of your test?

Comment: make sure you have the latest version (currently 2.0 RC3). But yes, outofmemory might still happen if you don't have enough memory (and can't set higher -Xmx values for your application). Maybe buy some RAM on ebay and upgrade the server. (Assuming that "2000" was not a typo)

Comment: @mkl
stack size of test is 1024M

Comment: Please check first whether increasing the stack size even more makes the exception go away. (Heap management and image rendering code may have changed considerably between Java versions.)

Comment: same problem here with final pdfbox 2.0 on widnows 7 and jdk 8 64 bit.. although the pdf is only 2mb and xmx set to 500mb